# Web scraping kahoot answer page not turning up children within class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I recently started learning web scraping in python, I have been tried to build a web scraper that find the answers for kahoots. To do this I need to get access to code within a class (or I believe it to be a class, I have not yet learnt html). How do I get access to the part that says `<div id="app">`. I have tried using the children method in Beautiful soup however this is not returning any results. I need access to the classes within this and I am wondering how to do this. I have attached my code below which cannot access objects within this container.
Many thanks

Edit

I am trying to find the answers for each question so that I can build a bot that plays the kahoot entirely by itself, Thank you for the responses,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/details/disney/0a39590a-cc49-4222-bf28-dd9da230d6bf'
website = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
find_class = soup.find(id='app')
print(list(find_class.children))
```

Comment: The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. What information do you need to get? I only see questions, not any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically by JavaScript. But you can use `requests` module to simulate it:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/details/disney/0a39590a-cc49-4222-bf28-dd9da230d6bf'

kahoot_id = url.split('/')[-1]
answers_url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/{kahoot_id}/card/?includeKahoot=true'.format(kahoot_id=kahoot_id)
data = requests.get(answers_url).json()

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for q in data['kahoot']['questions']:
    for choice in q['choices']:
        if choice['correct']:
            break
    print('Q: {:<70} A: {} '.format(q['question'].replace('&nbsp;', ' '), choice['answer'].replace('&nbsp;', ' ')))
```

Prints:

```
Q: What kind of animal is Goofy?                                          A: Dog 
Q: Who founded Disney?                                                    A: Walt Disney 
Q: Which country was it illegal to show Donald Duck?                      A: Finland 
Q: Why was it illegal in Finland?                                         A: He weren't wearing pants 
Q: Where does Mickey mouse live?                                          A: Mickey mouse clubhouse 
Q: Who is Mickey Mouse's girlfriend?                                      A: Minne Mouse 
Q: What is Minnie's favorite color?                                       A: Pink 
Q: Which year was Disney founded?                                         A: 1923 
Q: Who was the voices to Elsa and Anna in Frozen?                         A: Idina Menzel and Kristen Bell 
Q: What did Scrooge McDuck love to bath in?                               A: Coins 
Q: Who is Donald Duck's girlfriend?                                       A: Dolly Duck 
Q: Who are these guys?                                                    A: Huey, Dewey and Louie Duck 
Q: What did the Sleeping Beauty touch to fall asleep in a hundred years?  A: On a spindle 
Q: Why did Snow white's stepmother hate her?                              A: Shes pretty 
Q: What is the name of Jasmine's tiger?                                   A: Rajah 
Q: How many stepsisters did cinderella have?                              A: 2 
Q: Which hair color does Ariel have?                                      A: Red 
Q: What is the name of these two characters?                              A: Mowgli and Baloo
```